# extend TPolygon , add-points and delete-points

Tags: delphi

I need to extend the type type TPolygon = array of TPointF;  by an addpoint and deletepoint function

I was thinking of a solution of class helper function but this approach is not feasible for types. I have no clear Idea how to start that task.

```
///  concept for add points to polygon
procedure TPolygon.AddPoint(x, y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := length(???);

  setlength(???, i + 1);

  self[i].x := x;
  self[i].y := y;
end;


///  concept forremove points from polygon

procedure TPolygon.DeletePoint(x, y: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := length(???);

  setlength(???, i - 1);

  //  remove entry [i]

  //  renumber the other points ....
end;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `TList<TPointF>`?

Comment: Refactoring and extension of old existing project ( > 500 k LOC) , extension would be smalles change / lowest risk

Answer (score 2):

You can use a record helper for the array type:

```
type
  TPolygonHelper = record helper for TPolygon
    procedure Add(const X, Y: Single);
  end;

procedure TPolygonHelper.Add(const X, Y: Single);
var
  N: Integer;
begin
  N := Length(Self);
  SetLength(Self, N+1);
  Self[N].X := X;
  Self[N].Y := Y;
end;
```

Note that this requires Delphi XE3 extended record helpers.

Comment: Did this answer the question you asked?